# How to change the date that Win8 app will be published on?

Tags: windows-8

Does anyone know how to change the release date for a Windows 8 Store app? My app has been approved but I cannot move up the release date like in itunes connect.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't delete your question contents, there's rarely a good reason to actually remove the contents of your question entirely and just creates confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but you can't change the Date, you can cancel the release and submit it for certification again (will take another 5 - 6 days), and don't forget to select correct date this time around. Also you can try contacting customer support but not sure if that's going to help.

Comment: That is insanity. What a waste of tester resources.

Comment: it is, please mark it solved if this worked for you. also don't delete your original question content as it might be helpful to other people.